# Array only showing the last set of inputs

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
//global variable
counter=0;
var highestAvg=0;
var average = new Array(); 
var studObj = new Array(); 
var teachObj = new Array(); 
//Objects
var student = {
    studName:"", 
    studentId:"", 
    courses:['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 
    marks:[]}

var teacher = {
    profName:"", 
    course:"", 
    office:"", 
    email:""}

for(var i=0; i<30; i++)
{
    studObj[i] = Object.create(student);
    var check = prompt('Please enter students name(!!! to exit): ','');
    if(check !== '!!!')
    {
        studObj[i].studName = check;
        studObj[i].studentId = prompt('Please enter student ID: ','');
        var total=0;
        for(var j=0; j<4; j++)
        {
             studObj[i].marks[j] = prompt('Please enter student marks for ' + studObj[i].courses[j] + ' : ','');
            if(studObj[i].marks[j] > 100 || studObj[i].marks[j] < 0)
            {
                alert("Incorrect mark, please enter a correct mark!")
                j--;
            }
            else
            {
            total += Number(studObj[i].marks[j]);   
            }
        }
        average[i] = total/4;
        counter++;
    }
    else
    {
        break;
    }
    alert(average[i]);
}

var highestAvg = Number(average[0]);
for(var x=1; x<counter; x++)
{
    if((Number(average[x])) > highestAvg)
    {
        highestAvg = average[x];
        var z=x
    }
}
alert(highestAvg);

alert('The student with the highest overall average is: \nStudent Name: ' + studObj[z].studName + '\nStudent ID: ' + studObj[z].studentId + '\nCourses: ' + studObj[z].courses + '\nMarks: ' + studObj[z].marks + '\nAverage Mark: ' + average[z]);
```

I dont know why the marks array doesnt save to the studObj array, instead it gets overwritten. I have tried adding another array to hold the values but again it only shows the last 4 marks entered. Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: TIL there is something called [`prompt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.prompt) in Javascript. But I recommend you to not overuse it the way you overusing currently.

Comment: This is working fine for me, chrome 32.0.1700.107 m. Just ran it from the console and all values are assigned to the correct spots.  What browser and version is this to be implemented on?(it is kinda annoying though,  you should look into just using a form...) Also, instead of a counter, might I suggest using `array.length`?

Comment: Have you tried using `Math.max.apply(Math, average)` then looping over your `average` array to get the student number? Then there is no need for `var counter`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Global variables!!!

It doesn't change anything if you declare var or not in the global scope.
JavaScript works on function scope, putting every var it encounters on top, including your var i, j which in your example has become a global variable. If it happens you include more javascript on your page and it uses the same variable names you might end up with problems because of overriding the global scope variables.
To counter this, use an [IIFE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression) instead.

Reset your objects inside the loop like so:

```
total = 0;
studentCopy = Object.create(student);
studentCopy.marks = []; // resets the browsers' memory for marks[]
```

Adding objects into arrays will work, but pushing objects into arrays seems better. Also it's more readable and less likely to introduce bugs.

```
studObj[i].marks[j] = prompt('');
studObj[i].studentId = prompt('');
```

Can be something like:

```
studentCopy.marks.push(mark);
students.push(studentCopy);
```

If you save the index `i` to the average, the sorting can be improved like:

```
students.push(studentCopy);
average.push([[total / studentCopy.courses.length], [i]]);

highestAvg = average.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a[0] < b[0]; // use < so the maximum is at index 0
});
```

Your best student will be the index attached to the highestAvg which you can use as an index for students. And then you have all the information need.

```
bestStudent = students[highestAvg[0][1]];
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/tive/s3dQW/